# Mathematica 11.3 and 12.0 front-end start-up fails

Tags: front-end

When I start the front-end of Mathematica 11.3 or 12.0 on Scientific Linux 6.10, I see the splash screen and after it says "Opening Welcome Screen" the splash screen vanishes and nothing happens. There are no windows showing up and also no messages in the terminal. The program is still running and there is a "Mathematica" process, two "WolframKernel" processes, a "java" and a "XML.exe" process showing up in the output of `ps aux`. The only thing I can do is kill the process, e.g. via `Ctrl-C`.

This does not happen with Mathematica 11.1 or earlier versions and I can also successfully start just the kernel for 11.3 and 12.0 without the front-end. I've already removed the ~/.Mathematica folder, but nothing changes.

How do I even start to debug this?

Comment: While Mathematica _does_ support RHEL 6 (which Scientific Linux is based on), is there any good reason to use a _9 year old_ Linux distribution, with only maintenance support available? It seems like asking for trouble.

Comment: We'll that's not my decision to take. I'm just using infrastructure provided by the lab. Maybe I have to add that I also don't have any root access to the system.

Comment: Have you notified the system administrator? Do other people using the same system have the same problem? Could it be that the window just happened to move off-screen?  I would try to figure out how to move windows using the keyboard (or how to re-center them on the screen).

Comment: No, I didn't notify the admins yet, because I first wanted to try to get a clearer picture of what is happening at all. Hence my question of how to start debugging this. Concerning the window placement: No window shows up at all. There is none shown in the taskbar of my window manager and also Mathematica does not show up in the output of `xlsclients`. So I assume that no window is being created.